# Matplotlib issue when using xlwings - cannot load Qt platform plugin

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda, xlwings

When trying to embed a plot into an excel sheet using matplot lib as per the example http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html I get the following error when calling it from VBA.

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Has anyone come across this before?
Am using:
Anaconda 3-5.2.0
Python 3.6.5 64bit
Qt 5.9.4
PyQt5 5.9.2

Comment: Maybe it's related to this: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/954

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question...

I had a conflict on my Path which was causing the script to pick up the wrong .dll.

To solve run in CMD:
`where Qt5Core.dll`

In my case I got two results.

`C:\Program Files\Conda\Anaconda3\Library\bin\Qt5Core.dll
An\Another\Location\Qt5Core.dll`

Removeing the An\Another\Location from my Path solved the issue.